# Different version of jquery for Bootstrap and other library files

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Javascript library which only supports Jquery 1.5 and I have front end (Bootstrap and other such library) which require jQuery 1.8.

How can I use two set of jquery for different library files?

I am aware of no-conflict but facing some problem…

I have to load jQuery 1.5 first (some restriction)… then I load jQuery 1.8 then I load javascript library which require jQuery 1.8. Then I call Jquery. jQuery.noConflict.. Code is something similar:

```
 <script src="js/jquery.1.5.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.1.8.js"></script>
 //I want bootstrap to use v 1.8
 <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script>
 var $jq1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
 </script>
 //Now rest of program should use jQuery 1.5
```

Is this a valid solution??

Edit 1: based on reply by user3388636

I see some library using jQuery instead of $....I hope this works in that case also??

this should work??

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib-using-jq-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jQuery_1_5 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib-using-jq-1.8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_1_8 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Can i now set back $ value??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $ = jQuery_1_5.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Comment: I would wager that you are going to get an error doing that. Why do you need 1.5 if you are going to be using 1.8 with bootstrap?

Comment: Update the library to use a modern version of jQuery.

Comment: sadly that is not in my control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it can help you - http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.1.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dimensions.min.js"></script>

<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```