# How to avoid conflicts when adding Bootstrap and newer version of jQuery to an old and large system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

How to avoid conflicts when adding Bootstrap and newer version of jQuery to an old and large system?
Problem is, working with an old system that has an old version of jQuery included (jquery-1.8.3) and ordinary css - no Bootstrap yet.
Now it is time to start adding Boostrap (make the system responsive and give it a fresher look) and therefore newer jQuery version is needed.

As mentioned it is a quite large system. Going through all js code and add variables for `noConflict()` i.e: 
`var jq183 = jQuery.noConflict(true);` and same for new version `jq321 = jQuery.noConflict(true);` is not an 
option, the amount if existing js/jQuery code is huge. Is there any other way doing this? 
Including both versions with no adjusting is causing major conflicts and removing old version is not an option, 
since a lot of the old code is depending on that version.

I would really appreciate if someone has done this before and can help me with advice of how to do the fastest/ most effective way.

Comment: use a bootsrap version compatible with your old version of jquery or 2. convert the bootstrap js to be compatibile to your old version of jquery

Comment: There is no quick solution to badly written/maintained code. Your going to have to bite the bullet and refactor it or not upgrade

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different version of jquery for Bootstrap and other library files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614586/different-version-of-jquery-for-bootstrap-and-other-library-files)

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions. The decision to go for Bootstrap is already made at company level and above me. I decided to replace the old jQuery version causing conflicts and take it from there anyway.